# Get random data from table leads to strange result

Tags: postgresql

The following query should provide one line and not two. Working with Postgres 11.3.
What's wrong with this? The with select normalizes the indexes from 10 upto 120. The main select just restricts to an integer random between 10 and 120 and matches the xx column.
I don't understand the result Postgres get back.

```
postgres# select row_number() over(order by matid) * 10 as xx, matid  from materials;
 xx  | matid
-----+-------
  10 |    10
  20 |    20
  30 |    30
  40 |    40
  50 |    50
  60 |    60
  70 |    70
  80 |   110
  90 |   120
 100 |   130
 110 |   140
 120 |   150
(12 rows)

postgres@=# with am as (select row_number() over(order by matid) * 10 as xx, matid  from materials) select am.matid from am where xx::integer = (round((random()*110)/10)*10+10)::integer;
 matid
-------
    60
   120
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query may return 0 or 1 or more rows.
The `WHERE` clause:

```
where xx::integer = (round((random()*110)/10)*10+10)::integer
```

is executed again and again for each of the rows of the CTE, producing a new random number each time.
So the final resultset is unpredictable because the value returned by the expression `(round((random()*110)/10)*10+10)::integer` is not constant throughout the execution of the query.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=99349af916ec1f23bd4337ba1fa27812).

If you want a constant random number to be compared against all rows of the CTE, define it in another CTE, like this:

```
with 
  am as (
    select row_number() over(order by matid) * 10 as xx, 
           matid  
    from materials
  ),
  rnd as (select (round((random()*110)/10)*10+10)::integer n)
select am.matid 
from am 
where xx::integer = (select n from rnd);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1ee619c84f1dd171a95d644d82ae81a3).

Comment: @spec2019 fine if it is solved and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.